# Добавление экранного диктора в вебсайт

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, laravel

Как добавить и настроить экранного диктора в своем веб-сайте? Он должен произнести слова при нажатии.

Comment: Вставить видео с ютуба — подойдет?

Comment: На каком языке, любопытно :) по сути вам надо смотреть внешние сервисы, гуглоговорилка возможно подойдёт. Или интегрировать на платформу где сайт какие либо голосовые системы, но это вероятно не выполнимости в вашем случае.

Comment: @NewView Да я тоже хочу интегрировать готовую версию. Можете подсказать как сделать это? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вы хотите порекомендовать видео урок для просмотра? )

Comment: Например [rhvoice](https://github.com/Olga-Yakovleva/RHVoice/wiki) Как установить итд - в гугл  :)

Comment: А яндекс хвастался ж Алисой ) или Диалоги ? или это не то ?

Comment: Конечно можно: ```apt-get install festival``` Далее всё это прикручиваете к сайту. Будет трудно конечно, да и по-английски будет разговаривать, но тем не менее - разговаривать будет. Инфа - 146%.

Comment: Он ужасно разговаривает, полностью неживое решение. Единственное вменяемое по производимому результату на сегодняшний день это rhvoice, с учётом национальных языков конечно. Так же rhvoice умеет работать по d-bus что даёт ощутимо меньшую нагрузку на систему.

Comment: Ну, или так.  Просто, как вариант, предложил.

Comment: @NewView, оформи как ответ, я удалю свой!

Comment: @khrushid, кажется, я вопрос неправильно понял.

Comment: Твой ответ по сути правильный, я не претендую на 'звездочки', так что мое мнение, пусть будет :) и автор спрашивал наверняка что из области плуг-и-плай из области javascript, вряд ли его устроят предложенные нами решения :) @misdeed